# Criação de matriz dinâmica que armazeno texto com quebras

Tags: c, matriz, gerenciamento-de-memória

Tentativa de criar uma matriz dinâmica recorrendo a `malloc()`. Estou em dúvida se os parâmetros que envio para os diferentes ciclos da função estarão certos.

```
int size=0,i,j,n=20;
char str[]="Ola. Tudo bem?\n Sim e contigo?\n Comigo esta tudo bem! Que tens feito?\n Trabalho no projeto!\n";
char **matriz;
int *linha;
int *coluna;
size = strlen(str);
printf("%d\n",size);


*linha = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
*coluna = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));

for (i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    while (str[i]!='\n')
    {
        matriz[*linha][*coluna] = str[i];
    }
    if (str[i]=='\n')
    {
        *(linha++);
        *(coluna)=0;
    }
}
printf("%s",matriz);
```

Comment: Mas a `matriz` é suposto guardar que informação ? Um array de strings ? Isto é uma tentativa de fazer um split por `\n` ? Que resultado estaria a espera do ultimo `printf("%s",matriz);` ?

Comment: "fazer um printf que me mostrasse se a matriz ficou corretamente ordenada" - como assim? split por `\n` não iria ordenar as strings, apenas guarda-las na ordem em que aparecem.

Comment: Acho que o melhor é tentar tornar o mais claro possível o que o seu código pretende fazer, exemplificando até com dados de entrada e saída esperada. Digo isto porque há varias coisas que não estão bem no código o que não permitem perceber de forma exata a intenção, como por exemplo: utiliza a `linha` e `coluna` como array de inteiros, mas guarda o numero ASCII de uma letra, e depois incrementa o próprio ponteiro do array (`*(linha++);`) como se fosse um número. No fim mostra a `matriz` como uma `string` quando ela é um array de strings que nem tem as alocações em memoria com `malloc`

Comment: Fiz [este exemplo](https://ideone.com/NIJdYz) partindo do código apresentado. Veja se é isso que está a procura.

Comment: Existem muitas formas de fazer `split` algumas mais simples até utilizando `strtok`, eu tentei utilizar uma mais parecida à logica que tinha. Apenas utilizei a função `memcpy` para simplificar a copia dos caracteres, mas podiam ter sido copiados a mão com um `for`. O pormenor que torna o processo mais simples é contar primeiro os separadores para saber quantas strings tem de alocar

Comment: Sim é dessa forma que funciona. Se quiser posso elaborar uma resposta a explicar o que fiz e como fiz. Apenas não pus como resposta pois não tinha a certeza que era isso que estava de facto a tentar fazer.

Answer (score 3):

A resposta do Isac está correta. Resolvi só dar uma opção que dá maior eficiência de velocidade pagando o preço de fragmentar mais a memória. Se é uma opção melhor é debatível e precisaria analisar cada caso e testar muito bem. Só quis dar uma opção. Esta forma costuma ser mais idiomático para C.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[] = "Ola. Tudo bem?\n Sim e contigo?\n Comigo esta tudo bem! Que tens feito?\n Trabalho no projeto!\n";
    char **matriz = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 255);
    int linha = 0;
    matriz[linha] = malloc(255);
    for (int caractere = 0, coluna = 0; str[caractere] != '\0'; caractere++, coluna++) {
        if (str[caractere] == '\n' || str[caractere] == '\0') {
            matriz[linha][coluna] = '\0';
            matriz[linha] = realloc(matriz[linha], coluna + 1);
            matriz[++linha] = malloc(255);
            coluna = -1;
        } else {
            matriz[linha][coluna] = str[caractere];
        }
    }
    matriz = realloc(matriz, sizeof(char *) * linha);
    for (int i = 0; i < linha; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", matriz[i]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/HfEvqV). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gwphxoal-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/SplitString.c).

Me baseei no algoritmo do Isac mesmo, mas eliminei a necessidade de percorrer tudo 3 vezes.

Como há uma memória alocada em excesso precisa cortar o que não for usado. Há a limitação que só pode ter 255 frases com 254 caracteres cada. Nada foi verificado se isto está estourando, mas o algoritmo original também não verifica se o `malloc()` falha ou até outros problemas que possam ocorrer.

Também é possível ir realocando conforme a necessidade de caractere em caractere, mas isto provavelmente deixará mais lento. Tem como fazer algoritmos híbridos.

Comment: Aí já é outro código, é outro problema. Não tem como saber sem ver o código.

Comment: Não, precisa fazer outra, esta já foi respondida, se alterar as respostas dadas ficam inválidas e mistura problemas.

Comment: Cria outra pergunta. Tem erros visíveis neste código, mas parece que ele está executando como devia pelo menos nesse exemplo trivial, não?

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que indicou nos comentários está a tentar dividir uma `string` em pequenas `strings` de acordo com um separador, o que se costuma de chamar de `split`. No caso apresentado o separador a ser considerado é o `\n`, de mudança de linha.

O seu código tem vários pequenos problemas que não permitem que funcione corretamente:

- `*linha = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));` - Aqui fez com que o valor apontado pelo ponteiro `linha` seja um array de `ints`, o que não pode ser. Sendo `linha` um `int*` tem de apontar para um inteiro apenas. Este mesmo erro é visível como aviso de compilação:

  > assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by
  >   default]

  O mesmo acontece para o `coluna`.
- `while (str[i]!='\n')` - Este `while` testa enquanto a letra não é um `\n` mas dentro dele o `i` não avança, logo será um ciclo/laço infinito.
- `matriz[*linha][*coluna] = str[i];` - Aqui utiliza um array bidimensional `matriz` mas este não tem espaço alocado previamente, quer de forma estática ou dinâmica (com `malloc`), o que lhe vai dar um acesso a memória que não lhe pertence, e potencialmente dar um *Segmentation Fault*.
- `printf("%s",matriz);` - No fim a `matriz` é mostrada como se fosse uma `string` normal, ou seja um `char*` quando é na verdade um `char**`. A forma correta de mostrar é com um ciclo/laço.

Tentando pegar um pouco na lógica que tem e alterar de forma a que consiga fazer o *split*, pode utilizar outra abordagem. A que costuma ser mais simples é contabilizar a quantidade de separadores que existem e com essa quantidade alocar o array para essas `strings`. Depois cada string é alocada à medida que percorre a frase original e considerando cada um dos respetivos tamanhos:

```
int size=0;
char str[]="Ola. Tudo bem?\n Sim e contigo?\n\n Comigo esta tudo bem! Que tens feito?\n Trabalho no projeto!\n";

size = strlen(str);
printf("%d\n",size);

int separadores = 0, i;

//contar quantos separadores existem
for (i=0; i < size; ++i){ 
    if (str[i] == '\n'){
        separadores++;
    }
}

//a quantidade de elementos é o numero de separadores mais um
char **matriz = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(separadores+1));
int ultimo = 0, j=0;

//percorrer todas as linhas para construir cada string
for (i=0; i < size; ++i){ 
    if (str[i] == '\n' || i == (size-1)){ //se apanhou um '\n' ou está no fim
        if (i-ultimo > 1){ //if para considerar separadores seguidos

            //criar espaço para a string que apanhada até esta letra. A string vai 
            //desde o ultimo indice até ao i, logo tem o tamanho i-ultimo
            matriz[j] = malloc(sizeof(char)*(i-ultimo));
            memcpy(matriz[j], str+ultimo, i-ultimo); //copia os carateres
            matriz[j][i-ultimo]='\0'; //coloca o terminador no fim pela vez do \n
            j++; //j marca a string que se está a construir
        }

        ultimo=i+1;//atualiza o inicio da próxima string
    }
}

//mostrar todas as strings construidas. A quantidade delas é dada por j
for(i=0; i < j;++i){
    printf("%s\n",matriz[i]);
}
```

[Veja o exemplo desta lógica no Ideone](https://ideone.com/1z1FTq)

Note que utilizei a função `memcpy` para simplificar o código em si, mas esta apenas copia bytes de um sitio na memoria para outro. Podia implementar está logica à mão utilizando um simples `for`. A assinatura da função é:

```
memcpy(destino, origem, tamanho_em_bytes)
```

Para a utilizar é necessário incluir `<string.h>`.

Documentação para o [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/)